# Regex for Hexadecimal String 00FF...FF and FF...FF00

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I need to match 3 kinds of hexadecimal pattern (in string format already)

1. All FF
2. A byte followed by all FF
3. All FF, followed by a byte

For number 1, I used `^(FF)\\1*$` and it is working. For number 2 and 3, how to do that?

Comment: can you give an example of a `byte followed by all FF`

Comment: It's in the question title, such as 00FFFFFFFF

Comment: Why are you using `^(FF)\\1*$` for number 1? Doesn't `^(FF)+$` suffice?

Comment: @Jerry: I modify answer from another post. Tried both + and \1 and both gave the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a regex of the form

```
^([\dA-F]{2})?(FF)*([\dA-F]{2})?$
```

will match all strings of the form

```
FFFF
00FFFF
FFFF50
```

EDIT

To match seperatly

```
^([\dA-F]{2})?(FF)*$
```

matches

```
34FFFF
00FFFF
```

`^(FF)*([\dA-F]{2})?$`

matches the strings

```
FFFF50
FFFFAB
```

Comment: \d means digit right? A byte need two hexadecimal characters 0-9A-F

Comment: @David it was not clear in the begining. Have edited the answer. hope it does what you expect.

Comment: OK, it is working. But the answer need to be split into two, each having ([\dA-F]{2}) in front and another one behind.

Comment: @David meaning you need to match separtly strings containing in the begining and in the end??